# sequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m struggling to find the limits of:

$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n$:= $1+(-1)^n$

So the question is basically whether the sequence converges or not. I think so, at least as $n \to 0$ the limit is 2. I´m not sure whether this is a unique one or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "$\;n\to 0\;$ "? This doesn't seem to make sense for sequences indexed by the naturals....

Comment: ok. i exluded that possibility by providing the definition. But what exactly does convergence mean? In a previous exercise a had three limits. does it mean that a sequence, if it converges, converges to one specific value?

Comment: Yes, meaning: whenever a (real or complex) sequence converges (to a finite or to an infinite) limit, the limit is then unique. Furthermore, in this case **any** subsequence of that sequence converges *to the same limit*, meaning that if in a sequence you find two subsequences taht converge to *different* limits then the whole sequence cannot converge at all. I though think that you **must** read the very basics of limits of sequences before attempting to deal with the above. Try internet (google "limits"), your teacher, several books. Until you understand it fully you won't advance freely.

Comment: thanks alot...now it makes sense :)

Comment: DonAntonio, may I ask one last question to bring it all together. This sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n := 2^{-n}$ has two outer boundaries 1.As $n$ goes to $\infty$ than I`ll get $\frac{1}{2^n}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^\infty}$. So the first limit is $0$ 2.As $n$ goes to $-\infty$ than I`ll get $\frac{1}{2^n}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^{-\infty}}$. So the second limit is  $\infty$. Still this sequence doesnt converge because it doesnt tend to one specific,unique, value, which is the limit. Is it right?

Comment: Once again, @user113922 : it makes no sense of limit when $\;n\to 0\;$ or $\;n\to-\infty\;$ in sequences indexed by the naturals! The only limit that sequence may (and indeed) have is zero when $\;n\to\infty\;$ . You *really* must go back to the very basic in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$1+(-1)^n=\begin{cases}2&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is even}\\{}\\0&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: sorry dont get the hint

Comment: Can you point at two difference subsequences of your sequence that converge to **different** limits ? I think you still may have some problems grabbing the concept of limit since you write something about the limit when $\;n\to 0\;$ . This makes no sense with sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the two subsequents

1. $(a_{2k}) = 1+(-1)^{2k}\equiv 2 $
2. $(a_{2k+1}) = 1+(-1)^{2k+1} \equiv 0 $

That means your sequence has two limit points, hence it does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

I commented on another of your questions. @DonAntonio is right. It does not really sense to speak of $n\to 0$ for $n$ integer. To answer your question your sequence is not converging since it oscillates (see answer from DonAntonio). Can you understand why?

To expand:

let's call $a$ the limit of the sequence $a_n$ if the following conditions holds:
for each real number $\epsilon>0$ you can find a natural number $m$ such that for every $n>m$ you have $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$.

Is easy to see that for your sequence you cannot satisfy this definition, since it oscillates so it never gets arbitrarily close to a certain value (your limit).